# react native modal modalize statusbar background color

Tags: react-native, expo

If I use this libary:

https://github.com/jeremybarbet/react-native-modalize

and open a modal, then the background is light dark but status bar is white. How can I set the statusbar color as the same as the modal background color ?

This issue can solved in a Modal libary with statusbartranslucent. But this is another libary.

€: And my react-navigation header is also not translucent, its white

Code:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions, Image, ScrollView, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import AboveSize from './AboveSize';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
import { Picker as SelectPicker } from '@react-native-picker/picker';
import { Modalize } from 'react-native-modalize';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';

const Filter = () => {
  const modalizeRef = useRef(null);

  const onOpen = () => {
    modalizeRef.current?.open();
  };
  const [modalAmount, setModalAmount] = useState(false);
  const [sizeAmount, setSizeAmount] = useState('1');
  const size = [
    {
      key: "1",
      size: "XS"
    },
    {
      key: "2",
      size: "S",
    },
    {
      key: "3",
      size: "M"
    },
    {
      key: "4",
      size: "L"
    },
    {
      key: "5",
      size: "XL"
    },
    {
      key: "6",
      size: "XXL"
    },
    {
      key: "7",
      size: "XXXL"
    },
  ];
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="#fff" />
      <Text style={styles.subtitle}>In welchen größen und wie oft erhältlich ?</Text>
      <View>
        <AboveSize data={size} onPress={onOpen} />
      </View>
      <Modalize handlePosition="inside" modalHeight={200} ref={modalizeRef}>
        <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.modalButton} onPress={() => setSizeAmount(1)}>
            <Text style={styles.modalButtonText}>-</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TextInput style={styles.inputNumeric} keyboardType="numeric" value={sizeAmount} onChangeText={e => setSizeAmount(e)} />
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.modalButton} onPress={() => setSizeAmount(3)}>
            <Text style={styles.modalButtonText}>+</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Modalize>
    </View>
  )
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    padding: 12
  },
  modalContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 200,
  },
  subtitle: {
    fontFamily: 'montserrat-regular',
    color: '#333',
    fontSize: 20,
    marginTop: 0,
    textAlign: 'left'
  }
});

export default Filter;
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: Are you using this package on **expo** managed app?

Comment: Yes but why ? :D

Comment: If yes then, I will try to also run this package on an expo app. And try to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will wait of your answer

Comment: It will be nice if you share a screenshot of your problem.

Comment: @KamalHossain I editet my posts with a Picture.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234648/discussion-between-datastores11-and-kamal-hossain).